# Vue: updating transition name right before triggering transition doesn't render new transition

Tags: vue.js, vue-transitions

I'm seeing some behavior with Vue transitions that I don't understand. It'll be easier to explain by showing an example:

Given the following component:

```
<transition :name="transitionName">
    <div v-if="showMe">Hey</div>
</transition>
<button @click="transitionName='slide-left'; showMe = false">Left</button>
```

And that the following is true:

- There are css classes in place for the transition names `.slide-left` and `.slide-right` which does what their names imply.
- The initial state of `transitionName` is `slide-right`
- The initial state of `showMe` is true

I would expect the div to slide *left* when the button is clicked. However, it slides *right*.

A full reproducible is available here:

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',

  data: {
    showMe: true,
    transitionName: 'slide-right'
  }
});
```

```css
#demo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.slide-right-enter-active,
.slide-left-enter-active,
.slide-right-leave-active,
.slide-left-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.slide-left-enter,
.slide-left-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-right-enter,
.slide-right-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <transition :name="transitionName">
    <div v-if="showMe">Hey</div>
  </transition>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button @click="transitionName='slide-left'; showMe = false">left</button>
    <button @click="transitionName='slide-right'; showMe = !showMe">right</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

It contains both a "left" and "right" button, but the component will slide "right" regardless of which one you click.

I can fix it by changing the button's callback to this:

```
this.transitionName = 'slide-left';
Vue.nextTick(() => {
    this.showMe = false;
});
```

But I'm wondering why `nextTick` is necessary here, and whether there is a better way to solve the problem in general.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of Vue's update cycle. It queues all the updates and 'flushes' them at the same time so it can evaluate which sections of the page need to be changed and only patch those changes. When you use `Vue.nextTick` you're essentially telling Vue to wait until the next update cycle before setting `this.showMe = false`.

The [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue) explain it better than I do:

> ...Vue performs DOM updates asynchronously. Whenever a data change is observed, it will open a queue and buffer all the data changes that happen in the same event loop. If the same watcher is triggered multiple times, it will be pushed into the queue only once. This buffered de-duplication is important in avoiding unnecessary calculations and DOM manipulations. Then, in the next event loop “tick”, Vue flushes the queue and performs the actual (already de-duped) work...
>
> ...For example, when you set `vm.someData = 'new value'`, the component will not re-render immediately. It will update in the next “tick”, when the queue is flushed. Most of the time we don’t need to care about this, but it can be tricky when you want to do something that depends on the post-update DOM state... In order to wait until Vue.js has finished updating the DOM after a data change, you can use `Vue.nextTick(callback)` immediately after the data is changed. The callback will be called after the DOM has been updated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't really answer my question. I'm aware of what nextTick does. What I don't understand is why it's needed in this case. I updated the question to make that more clear.

Comment: If you set `this.showMe` and `this.transitionName` in the same cycle, your transition will still have `slide-right` as its name. It needs to set the transition name in the first cycle so it can be correctly evaluated in any future cycle where the value of `this.showMe` is changed

Comment: Why will the transition have `slide-right` as it's name? When setting `showMe` and `transitionName` in the same cycle, they will both be added to the queue and flushed for the next cycle. So when `showMe` becomes `false`, `transitionName` will be `slide-left`.

Comment: Without knowing *exactly* how Vue works internally, I couldn't say. I guess it's just the order in which the transition is processed with the state of the component.